# Writing function including pandas query with numeric value in function cal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function with two calls, one which is the data frame and the other which is some numeric value. I get the error that name "t is not defined." When I hard code that numeric value, everything works well.

Here is minimal reproducible example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

def my_fun(t, df):
    l = df.query('A == t')
    return l

my_fun(1, df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `@`:

```
def my_fun(t, df):
    l = df.query('A == @t')
    return l
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with
> an ‘@’ character like @a + b.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an f-string to replace the value of the variable `t` in your query string instead of a literal `"t"` string:

```
l = df.query(f"A == {t}")
```

---

Complete code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

def my_fun(t, df):
    l = df.query(f'A == {t}')
    return l

print(my_fun(1, df))
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
```

Comment: That works, and I am grateful for the answer; why did it not work as is? Apparently 10 minutes need to pass before I can accept the answer.

Comment: Because you were always comparing the column A with `t`, which (as stated by the exception) is not defined (pandas does not know what to do with that "name").  You can checkout the difference in the query strings by printing the f-string before using it in the query: `print(f"A == {t}")`.